# Using Platform Invoke in a C# dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I came up with a problem that causes headache.

Let me first describe the general idea:

1) I got some native c++ code, which i wrote a wrapper for, to make accessible via Platform     Invoke. The result is, let us say wrapped.dll.

2) I got a c# Project that contains an application, app.exe and a class library, let it be plugin.dll.

3) I want to import the Wrapped.dll in in my plugin.dll

Thats it in general.

Now the problem:

The idea is importing the wrapped.dll, using Pinvoke in c#

```
[DLLImport("Wrapped.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void someFunction();
```

The import works just fine, as long i do it in my c# application main(). But the idea is to get access to it from my plugin.dll. For some reason this does not work and i get an exception:

```
System.DLLnotFoundException in Plugin.dll
```

It is not about the path of the wrapped.dll. I tried the standard \bin folder of the pluging.dll, the application, both and absolut path (e.g "C.\User\Projects\").

What i want to ask now is:

Is a Platform Invoke only possible in an application? Is there some kind of extra step to make it accessible in a dll?

Please note that it is not about my wrapper.dll. I can import and call it from my application main(). And i am pretty sure that it is not about the path.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: I'm pretty sure it *is* about the path. The unmanaged DLL needs to be in the same folder as the executable that is calling the library that is doing the P/Invoke.

Comment: Yup, storing it in the wrong directory is surely the cause.  Windows has no reason whatsoever to look in an arbitrary "plugin" or "bin" directory and pays no attention to where the CLR found the assembly.  You have to help it find it, SetDllDirectory is a boilerplate way.  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() to append the path to the PATH environment variable is a way to do that without pinvoke.  Programmers like organizing directories, the operating system doesn't.

Comment: Oh my Lord. It has been fixed by changing the assembly from referring directly to the dll, to a plugin project reference. Sorry for stealing your time :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to be annoying but I would say that the path is the issue.

Anyway, there is another common mistake when wrapping DLL's in .Net ... Check your compile Platform, is the Wrapper.dll 32bit/64bit like Plugin.dll?

In order to avoid confusion, try not to use "Any CPU".

Comment: Hey. No it was not about the Platform. I'll give you right answer anyway for your first sentence :).